# Why are the values passed to a method saved as an object?

Tags: matlab, class, argument-passing

I have a class with a scheduler function that is supposed to insert characters into a cell array:

```
classdef timeline < handle
properties
    schedule
    i
    %other properties
end

methods
    %other functions
    function t = timeline()
         %other initializations
         t.schedule = cell(1,738);
         t.i = 1;
    end
    function scheduler(t, g, fT)
        if nargin == 2
            fT = t.i;
        end
        if strcmp(g,'science')
            'science' % eclipse occurs after
            for j = (fT+t.sTime+1) : (fT+t.sTime+1+t.eTime)
                t.schedule{j} = 'e';
            end
        elseif strcmp(g,'pass')
            'pass' % science occurs 2 hrs after end
            for j = (fT) : (fT+t.pTime)
                t.schedule{j} = 'p'
            end
            for j = (fT+t.pTime+121) : (fT+t.pTime+120+t.sTime)
                t.schedule{j} = 's';
            end
            scheduler(t, 'science', fT+t.pTime+120);
        end
    end
end
end
```

In the command window, I define my object `t = timeline()` and a mode `g = 'pass'` and then call the scheduler, `t.scheduler(t,g)`.

It doesn't change the `schedule` property. What's going on inside the `if` statements to write the schedule isn't the problem I am concerned with. I put outputs in each part of the `if` statement, and found that `strcmp` is returning false and skipping over the whole block. So, I added a break point in the scheduler function, and found that for some reason `g` is passed to the function as another `timeline` object instead of the string `'pass'`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a method for an object you can use dot notation or function notation. Dot notation means you call the method using the dot operator on the object instance. For example,

```
obj.methodName(args);
```

In function notation you pass the object instance variable as the first argument to the method. For example,

```
methodName(obj, args);
```

Both the above calls are equivalent and call the same method in the object. In both the calls MATLAB passes obj as input to the method. Note the absence of `obj` as an argument in the dot notation. In dot notation `obj`, is added as an input argument before your args. In your code you are mixing both of these options. So you got two obj arguments for your method.

Relevant documentation is at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-invocation.html

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the link.